# My AutoCompleteTextView is working fine, but no marker is pointing

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-asynctask, maps, markers

Here are my codes for my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

AutoCompleteTextView atvPlaces;   
GoogleMap mMap;    
final int PLACES=0;
final int PLACES_DETAILS=1;    

private static final String TAG="google";
private static final String LOG_TAG="SearchViewActivity1";
private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";
private static final String API_KEY = "MY API KEY";
private static final String API = (PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);

private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {

    ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&components=country:ph");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {
        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

        // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
        resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }

    return resultList;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map); 
    mMap = mapFragment.getMap();

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.atv_places);
    autoCompView.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view));
    autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}



private class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<String> resultList;

    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }};
        return filter;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
ListView lv = (ListView) adapterView;
    SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) adapterView.getAdapter();

    HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) adapter.getItem(position);                    

    // Creating a DownloadTask to download Places details of the selected place
    DownloadTask DownloadTask = new DownloadTask();

    // Getting url to the Google Places details api
    String url = getPlaceDetailsUrl(hm.get("reference"));                    

    // Start downloading Google Place Details
    // This causes to execute doInBackground() of DownloadTask class
    DownloadTask.execute(url);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}



    private String getPlaceDetailsUrl(String ref){

        // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
        String key = "key=YOUR_API_KEY";

        // reference of place
        String reference = "reference="+ref;                    

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";            

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = reference+"&"+sensor+"&"+key;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        return url;
    }





/** A class, to download Places from Geocoding webservice */
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        String data = null;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
                try{                            
                        data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
                }catch(Exception e){
                         Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
                }
                return data;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){

                ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
                parserTask.execute(API);
        }

}
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);


            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url 
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url 
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

    return data;

}


class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

    JSONObject jObject;


    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;            
        GeocodeJSONParser parser = new GeocodeJSONParser();

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            /** Getting the parsed data as a an ArrayList */
            places = parser.parse(jObject);

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }
        return places;
    }


// Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){           

        // Clears all the existing markers          
        mMap.clear();

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

            double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));                
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

            String name = hmPlace.get("formatted_address");
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(name);


            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);    

            // Locate the first location
            if(i==0)

                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), latLng.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        }

}}
```

I get this error (`logcat`):

```
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.google.MainActivity$PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.SimpleAdapter
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at com.example.google.MainActivity.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:195)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:902)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.access$500(AutoCompleteTextView.java:91)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownItemClickListener.onItemClick(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1192)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onKeyUp(AbsListView.java:2890)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.widget.ListView.commonKey(ListView.java:2258)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.widget.ListView.onKeyUp(ListView.java:2113)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.onKeyUp(ListPopupWindow.java:912)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onKeyUp(AutoCompleteTextView.java:672)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2633)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7205)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1920)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1395)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2370)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3701)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3651)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2818)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-24 16:08:30.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16994):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think its a noob question but please help! Thanks!

Comment: ur getting `classcastexception` *AutoCompleteAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.SimpleAdapter*

Comment: Can you tell me what should I change?

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayAdapter doesn't inherit from the SimpleAdapter which will cause this error.

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) adapterView.getAdapter();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

To cast an object it must be of the same datatype or be inherited from the object you're trying to cast to.

Try switching it to :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) adapterView.getAdapter();
```

The method call you make is inherited so there should be no issues :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getItem(int)

Hope this helps.

Edit : Sorry, I also noticed :

```
HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) adapter.getItem(position);
```

Your adapter has the data type of String and this will never work. It has to be :

```
String hm = ( String ) adapter.getItem(position);
```

I've also set the Adapter cast to consider the data type too.

Comment: String url = getPlaceDetailsUrl(hm.get("reference"));   
error in ".get" part and i dont know why....

Comment: That's because get isn't a method of the String object it's a member of the Map interface. Just change it to `String url = getPlaceDetailsUrl( hm );`